Syncing Avenza maps across devices through cloud storage
Is there a way to sync Avenza maps across devices through cloud storage?
Perhaps aomething like QfieldCloud storage, but the cost is pretty steep.
The Avenza files data are stored in dropbox. So we need a utility to sync these files.
We are using QGIS.
Say 2 field workers mark different locations. They both have to be integrated, so that everyone can see what they have done. This is to allow for greater team collaboration.
If not Avenza, are they any other systems that have these syncing features?

It looks like there is a Dropbox import feature option for Avenza.  https://support.avenzamaps.com/hc/en-us/articles/5524768250004-Importing-Map-Features  Or course, the collector would need to upload those data for that to work.  Plus, there is no Avenza API so no 'automation' - Users would need to manually import those data.

Yes avenza does have a dropbox feature. The user has to do the syncing themselves. When there are 2 or more people working on one project, it would get harder to sync and unify all their input.

@MelanieStevens If the field workers upload their files to Dropbox as KML files, there are multiple utilities (online and not) that will merge the files into a single KML file. You would need to do some scripting on a server somewhere to periodically grab the files from dropbox, then merge them, perhaps using GDAL, then upload to Dropbox. As already noted, each field worker would have to manually fetch the merged file from Dropbox. An elegant solution would notify the field workers that there is a new merged file. You might still need a method to resolve conflicting marks if that might occur.

@MelanieStevens - at the risk of stating the obvious, your field workers will need data connectivity to upload and download, something not to taken for granted in the areas I find myself. With enough work they could probably embed the data into a text message that newer iPhones will send via satellite, but that would get complicated very fast.

OK, this makes sense, uploading as KML and merging them at the cloud, which is essentially what qfieldcloud is doing.

And re: remote location data upload, point noted. Thank you.
